# jquery 3.2.1 can't run ajax but jquery 1.3 success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

It's really strange.
I import jquery in my jsp file to run ajax.
When I use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Ajax **not works**.

When I use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Ajax works.

Code in **jsp** file is like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").click(function () 
      {
        alert("0");
        var uname=$('#uname').val();
        var passwd=$('#passwd').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType: 'application/json',

            url:"http://localhost:8080/login",
            data:{"uname":uname,"passwd":passwd},
            success:function(data){

            alert(data.toString());
                 ........
```

**jquery 1.3 and 1.4** version can get `alert("0")` and `alert(data.toString())`.
 But when I change to higher version like **jquery 1.5 or 2.1 or 3.2.1**, ajax not works and i can not get `alert(data.toString())`. **Why ????** I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change  dataType parameter from `application/json` to `json` or `jsonp`